# Leaflet.js - Create marker and show popup on a map

Tags: javascript, html, leaflet

I'm using [Leaflet JavaScript API](https://leafletjs.com/) to create a popup when I click on a certain HTML element. The problem is that the popup won't display on my map. I'm not sure what is wrong with my code.

Below is an example of a feature from the json file. Notice I assigned the whole json object as a `var dataset` for convenient.

```
var dataset = {
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "stemburo": "Sporthal Nieuwland",
        "aantal_stemmen": 3753,
        "lat": 52.2006665,
        "lng": 5.3758691,
        "Actief": 34,
        "Amersfoort 2014": 348,
        "Blanco lijst Chel": 5,
        "Burger Partij Amersfoort": 258,
        "Christen Democratisch App\u00e9l": 556,
        "ChristenUnie": 350,
        "DENK": 117,
        "Democraten 66": 525,
        "GroenLinks": 345,
        "Partij van de Arbeid": 239,
        "Socialistische Partij": 189,
        "Staatkundig Gereformeerde Partij": 42,
        "Volkspartij voor Vrijheid en Democratie": 717,
        "Vrede en Recht": 28
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          5.3758691,
          52.2006665
        ]
      }
    }
```

Below is a part of my JavaScript code to create the HTML elements. I used JQuery's `$.each` to read the dataset. I assigned the 'stemburo' property value (from the json object) as the element's id attribute .

When an element is clicked, it checks if the clicked id value is the same as one of the `properties.stemburo` value. Subsequently, a popup should be display based on the property's coordinates.

```
$.each(dataset.features,function(key,val){
    var stemlocaties =val.properties.stemburo;
    var newElement= document.createElement('a');
    newElement.id= stemlocaties;
    newElement.className='list-group-item list-group-item-action';
    newElement.innerHTML=stemlocaties;
    document.getElementById('stemlocaties').appendChild(newElement);

    newElement.onclick=function(){
        if (val.properties.stemburo===this.id){
            var lng = val.geometry.coordinates[0];
            var lat = val.geometry.coordinates[1];
            L.popup()
              .setLatLng([lat,lng])
              .setContent('New popup text!')
              .openOn(map);

        }
    };

    });
```

I'm still new to JavaScript. Any feedback would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's another way to solve the issue you are facing. If you read the [leaflet.js docs](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.2.html), can find out how to add a [marker](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.2.html#marker) and attach a [popup dialog](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.2.html#popup) to it.

Here's the line that adds a marker and attaches a popup to it. `L.marker(location).addTo(myMap).bindPopup(popupContent)`.

It takes a little more effort to arrange the data to be able to easily map over it, create a location, and popupContent variables which can be used to fill the popup with information. Here's an example of how to use the dataset you provided and create markers with popups.

```js
// Create the map and set the view and some properties
var myMap = L.map('mapid').setView([52.2, 5.37], 12);
L.tileLayer('https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoibWFwYm94IiwiYSI6ImNpejY4NXVycTA2emYycXBndHRqcmZ3N3gifQ.rJcFIG214AriISLbB6B5aw', {
  // maxZoom: 5,
  attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, ' +
    '<a href="https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, ' +
    'Imagery © <a href="https://www.mapbox.com/">Mapbox</a>',
  id: 'mapbox.streets'
}).addTo(myMap);

var dataset = {
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "stemburo": "Sporthal Nieuwland",
        "aantal_stemmen": 3753,
        "lat": 52.2006665,
        "lng": 5.3758691,
        "Actief": 34,
        "Amersfoort 2014": 348,
        "Blanco lijst Chel": 5,
        "Burger Partij Amersfoort": 258,
        "Christen Democratisch App\u00e9l": 556,
        "ChristenUnie": 350,
        "DENK": 117,
        "Democraten 66": 525,
        "GroenLinks": 345,
        "Partij van de Arbeid": 239,
        "Socialistische Partij": 189,
        "Staatkundig Gereformeerde Partij": 42,
        "Volkspartij voor Vrijheid en Democratie": 717,
        "Vrede en Recht": 28
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          52.2006665,
          5.3758691
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
};

// map over the dataset features, create a marker for each and link a popup.
dataset.features.map(function(feature) {
 const location = feature.geometry.coordinates;
  let partijen = Object
   .keys(feature.properties)
    .filter(item => !['stemburo', 'lat', 'lng'].includes(item));
  
  const popupContent = 
   '<h2>' + 
     feature.properties.stemburo + 
    '</h2>' + 
    partijen.map((naam) => '<p><strong>' + naam + '</strong>: ' + feature.properties[naam] + '</p>').join('');
  
  // add the marker and popup to the map.
  L.marker(location).addTo(myMap).bindPopup(popupContent);
});
```

```css
#mapid {
  height: 400px;
}

.leaflet-popup-content p {
    margin: 3px 0 !important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.3/dist/leaflet.css" integrity="sha512-Rksm5RenBEKSKFjgI3a41vrjkw4EVPlJ3+OiI65vTjIdo9brlAacEuKOiQ5OFh7cOI1bkDwLqdLw3Zg0cRJAAQ==" crossorigin="" />

<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.3/dist/leaflet.js" integrity="sha512-tAGcCfR4Sc5ZP5ZoVz0quoZDYX5aCtEm/eu1KhSLj2c9eFrylXZknQYmxUssFaVJKvvc0dJQixhGjG2yXWiV9Q==" crossorigin=""></script>

<div id="mapid"></div>
```

Here's also a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/roycode/9tw1Lpa0/1) with the same example.

Comment: Hi @Wonka, let me know if this solved your issue. If it did, don't forget to mark this answer as the accepted one. This will help folks looking at this later to know that we came to a solution. Thanks! :)